# Using the cache android

Tags: java, android

I implemented an application that are fed from an XML stream.
The XML feed changes every once daily.

I want to know if I can meter the xml file caching for one day for each round has not questioned the service that provided the xml But every day at midnight I want it retrieves the new version of XML

cordially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the xml file in the sdcard

Answer (score 1):

You can save the xml on card and replace it every 24 hours (use `filelastModified()` to get last time the file was modified)